# Getting SIGKILL when running study optimization with Optuna on PyCharm

Tags: python, pycharm, pytorch, optuna

I am trying to run a study, using the optimize function with the default sampler and Median pruner.
every run crashes, sometimes after 1 succefull trial sometimes without completing any.
The crash message is: Process finished with exit code 137 (interrupted by signal 9: SIGKILL)

### Expected behavior

running a study

### Environment

- Optuna version:
  2.0.0
- Python version: 3.8
- OS:QubeOS with debian 10 VM
- (Optional) Other libraries and their versions:
  Pytorch '1.5.0+cpu'

### Error messages, stack traces, or logs

Process finished with exit code 137 (interrupted by signal 9: SIGKILL)

what cause such an error?

Comment: How do you execute the command? To me, it seems am error on a C libraries (exception, e.g. accessing invalid memory), which cause kernel to kill the process, so without printing the python exception stack. Or it can be also a bug in python, or just hardware problem (memory overheating is also known to cause this)

Answer (score 0):

One likely situation is that your process consumes a lot of memory and gets killed by the operating system's OOM killer. You can monitor the memory consumption of your process using a tool like `top` and see if it uses a lot of memory.

You can also run `dmesg` in the console and look for messages from the OOM killer in the output. The OOM killer will usually print there which process it killed. Check whether the process ID is the one of your process.

In case the process is indeed killed by the OOM killer then the only remedy probably is to reduce the memory consumption of the program (or get a bigger machine).

Comment: thanks for the comment! I actually did it and the memory consumption is reasonable ~ 50%.. I'm clueless at the moment.
when looking at dmesg it does show OOM kill process... , how can it be that the top doesn't show this memory peak?

Comment: It could be that at some point the program attempts one very big allocation and that is what makes the OOM killer kick in. Another option is to run your program through a debugger like gdb and see at which point the program gets the SIGKILL. There also is a tool called mtrace (see `man mtrace`) that can trace memory allocations at the C level. I am not really an expert on this OOM killer business. You may want to read up on this. A good start is the NOTES section in the Linux man page for `malloc`

Answer (score 0):

you can play safe and use

```
gc_after_trial=True
```

there is study.optimize(timeout=300) but i didnt manage to get this to work
there is also timeout and n_trial limit you can set if you are using tpesampler in HyperbandPruner.
lastly what work for me is lower n_jobs (i set to -1 and has tendency to spike all my cores to 100% and finally just crash).